# Why am I getting 404 error page on end pages of the pagination in wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have used pagination here in the searh.php of my WordPress site. I have kept posts_per_page =10, so based on this if the total search results are 105 then, I do get 11 page numbers listed in the pagination tab. But, the 11th page results to 404 error page. The issue gets resolved when posts_per_page is changed to 15 but, why is it not working for end pages when posts_per_page is set to 10 ? Nothing has been edited in functions.php to implement pagination.

```
<?php
// Get the start time
$start_time = microtime(true);
get_header();
$blog_type = 'standard'; // standard, grid, masonry.
$class = 'bb-standard';
?>
<?php
$s = get_search_query();

// set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = array(
    's' => $s,
    'nopaging'               => false,
    'posts_per_page'         => '15',
    // 'post_type'              => 'post', 
    // 'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'paged'                  => $paged,
    'page'                   => $paged
);
?>
<style>
    ul.searchlistspz{
        margin-left:0px;
    }   
    h2.results-heading{
        margin-top:25px;
    }
    ul.searchlistspz > li{
        list-style: none;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #e7e9ec;
        border-radius: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        min-width: 1px;
        -webkit-transition: all linear .2s;
        transition: all linear .2s;
        height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    ul.searchlistspz > li > a{
        margin: 0 0 5px;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #047cc3;
    }
    ul.searchlistspz > li > p{
        margin: 0 0 5px;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        color: #666;
    }
    ul.searchlistspz > li > a:hover{
        background:#fff;
        opacity:0.8;
    }
    .pagination {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

    .pagination li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .pagination .page-link {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #333;
    }

    .pagination .page-item.active .page-link {
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #337ab7;
    color: #fff;
    }

    .pagination .page-item.disabled .page-link {
    opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .pagination .page-item.disabled .page-link:hover {
    cursor: default;
    }

    /* ul.searchlistspz > li > a:visited{
        color: #A31dd3;
    } */
    @media (max-width:767px){
        ul.searchlistspz > li > a{
                padding: 12px 20px;
        }
    }
</style>
<?php
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
// Get the end time
$end_time = microtime(true);

// Calculate the total time in seconds
$total_time = $end_time - $start_time;

if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
    _e("<div><h2 class='results-heading' style=''>Search Results for: " . get_query_var('s') . "</h2>");
    echo $the_query->found_posts . ' results found in ' . number_format($total_time, 2) . ' seconds.';;
    ?>
    <ul class="searchlistspz">
        <?php
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $title = get_the_title();
            // Get the post content and excerpt
            $content = get_the_content();
            $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
            // Check if the excerpt contains the searched query
            if (stripos($excerpt, $s) !== false) {
                // If the excerpt contains the searched query, use it as the result
                $highlighted_excerpt = preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($s, '/') . ')/i', '<strong>$1</strong>', $excerpt);
                $result = $highlighted_excerpt;
            } else {
                $pos = stripos($content, $s);
                if ($pos !== false) {
                    $excerpt = substr($content, $pos, 200); // extract 200 characters starting from the position of the keyword
                    $excerpt = wp_trim_words($excerpt, 55, ''); // trim to 55 words
                } else {
                    $excerpt = wp_trim_words($excerpt, 55, ''); // keyword not found, set excerpt to blank
                }
                $highlighted_content = preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($s, '/') . ')/i', '<strong>$1</strong>', $excerpt); // Highlight the searched query
                $result = $highlighted_content;
            }
            ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
                <p><?php echo $result; ?></p>
            </li>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="pagination">
        <?php 
            // // Display pagination only if there's more than one page
            if ($the_query->max_num_pages > 1) {
            $currentPage = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

            echo '<ul class="pagination">';
            if($currentPage > 1)
            echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.get_pagenum_link($currentPage - 1).'"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>';

            for ($i = 1; $i <= $the_query->max_num_pages; $i++) {
                echo '<li class="page-item '.(($currentPage == $i) ? 'active' : '').'"><a class="page-link" href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
            }
            if ($currentPage != $the_query->max_num_pages) {
            echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.get_pagenum_link($currentPage + 1).'"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            }
 ?>
    </div>
    <!-- 
-->
</div>
<?php
    // Clean up after the query and pagination.
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
?>
    <div>
        <h2 class='results-heading' style=''>Nothing Found</h2>
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            <p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
<?php get_sidebar('search'); ?>

<?php
get_footer();
```